# Excel Vlookup against SQL database

Tags: vba, t-sql

I normally vlookup my data against a table (database) in another workbook. (Excel to Excel --that's normally everyone does).
Since my table (database) grows more than 1.4 million rows therefore I need to transfer it to SQL Table in MS SQL Database.
I cannot move regular excel files just for Vlookup to SQL.
How do I vlookup excel against SQL tables.
Any solution with visual basic OR TSQL to fulfill requirement.
thanks

Comment: It seems that you only have 1 table so there is no need to use an enterprise level RDBMS like MS SQL. You can either use Access or Power Pivot if you are the only user to query the database. If you still insist on using MS SQL, then my suggestion is to create a read-only excel file and use ADO in VBA to query the data in MS SQL Database. This way you can store your data in SQL Server and CRUD them by T-SQL in read-only excel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, obviously, the limitation is just over a million rows, so you can use a Power Pivot Table to connect to multiple CSV files, aggregate the date you need, even if the total number of rows is over a million, and consolidate everything in one worksheet.

[image]

See the links below for more ideas of how to do this.

https://powerpivotpro.com/2017/01/import-csv-files-folder-filenames-excel/

http://sfmagazine.com/post-entry/january-2016-excel-combining-many-csv-files/

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-pivottable-with-an-external-data-source-db50d01d-2e1c-43bd-bfb5-b76a818a927b

Answer (score 0):

You would use the 'Where' clause!

```
Sub ImportFromSQLServer()

Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim Server_Name As String
Dim Database_Name As String
Dim User_ID As String
Dim Password As String
Dim SQLStr As String
Dim RS As ADODB.Recordset
Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset

Server_Name = "your_server_name_here"
Database_Name = "your_DB_name_here"
'User_ID = "******"
'Password = "****"

SQLStr = "select * from dbo.TBL Where EMPID = '2'" 'and PostingDate = '2006-06-08'"

Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & ";"
'& ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

RS.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic

    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
        .ClearContents
        .CopyFromRecordset RS
    End With

RS.Close
Set RS = Nothing
Cn.Close
Set Cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This code is to bring sql table data to excel using VBA. I mentioned in my post that sql table database has now over 2 million rows. Therefore cannot import into excel to vlookup against other working excel files. I need solution where I can took input data to a temporary sql table and then look up against database table. Then move back the input + results into excel again.  This is the optimal I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to do that:

googling "excel connect to sql server" brings the result (description how to connect to a sql data source, to long to cite it here)

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/connect-a-sql-server-database-to-your-workbook-power-query-22c39d8d-5b60-4d7e-9d4b-ce6680d43bad

Then, when you have the connection, write your own lookup function in VBA, doing whatever you like.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution :-)